# Is there a way to get attributes and uniforms in Vulkan after the vkCreateShaderModule?

Tags: glsl, vulkan, spir-v

Like in opengl we can do glGetActiveAttrib and glGetActiveUniform.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

No. You're expected to either introspect the SPIR-V yourself or a priori know what locations/bindings you used for the various interface variables in your shader.